# Philosophy histories adopting the topical approach, presenting each branch independently ? (Reference request)

Tags: reference-request, history-of-philosophy

There are mainly two ways to expose the history of philosophy : (1) by presenting authors in a chronological order, and explaining one at a time the whole system of each author ( with maybe altering a bit the chronology in order to take into account geographical area membership) (2) by proceeding in a topical manner, that is, by exposing separately the development of each branch of philosophy.

I think the second way is really useful for students. For acquiring a philosophical culure requires seeing the big picture and being able to make comparisons between the main doctrines; and this is what allows the topical approach.

It seems to me that few histories of philosophy have attempted the second way.

I only can see :

- Kenny, New History Of Western Philosophy ( which combines way (1) and (2) )
- Moore& Bruder, Philosophy, The Power Of Ideas.

Could you point out other references taking this stance towards the history of philsoophy?

Comment: "*The idea of a topical history of philosophy seems a good one, if opinions were so thoroughly disciplined that it recognized a certain number of precise problems, stated in unambiguous terms. Scholastic philosophers might make such a synopsis to their satisfaction. But isn't the great difficulty today that no two persons or schools have the same problems or the same terms?*" Santayana. It isn't science, the result of uniformization is not really history but the author's own narrative on the theme. [Windelband's history](https://archive.org/details/historyofphiloso007974mbp) is an example.

Comment: In support of Conifold's input; Sometimes assumptions are made that there is some type of continuity thread running through the History of Philosophy. This can prove a dangerous misstep. What has often resulted is a simplistic grouping of philosophers who, in fact, share little or nothing in common, like calling, Descartes, Spinoza and Leibnitz, Rationalists. Or calling Kierkegaard and Sartre, Existentialists. For a lengthier treatment of this problem see my 'Footnote Fixation'. At: charlessaunders5.academia.edu. Read the abstract first to see if it interest you. CMS